# Get technical information on screen fields without documentation

Tags: sap-erp, dynpro

In SAP ERP GUI, for a report selection criteria: How can I get the technical information associated with a screen field, when there is no documentation maintained for that field?

Normally, when there is a documentation for that field, I can press F1 while the field is in focus. This will bring up the help window. In the help window, there is a button for technical information. Pressing it will bring up a dialog containing further technical details associated with the screen field. How can I get this info if no documentation has been maintained for the field?

TIA,
Martin

Comment: An empty help window should appear in any case. Could you please specify which report and which field you have in mind?

Comment: The report is a custom one developed internally. No window pops up when I press F1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Occasionally selection screen fields and objects do not show a documentation window at all, and instead simply display the information message:

```
No documentation available
```

In this situation, one trick is to use the variant screen for the report. With the report selection screen open, type [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)+[s](/questions/tagged/s) to enter the variant screen, then press the `Technical Name` button to toggle the display of the technical name for all the selection screen fields.

This will only give you the internal parameter name specific to that report. To find more information about the parameter field, you would still need to look at the ABAP code to see how it is defined.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there must be a trick with the variant but I did not find the Technical Name button before. This solves my question.